# Virtual Sitecore User Group - Budapest #10

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

Join for the first ever Hungarian virtual Sitecore meetup! 2 presenations will be held by 2 hungarian Sitecore developers.

---

### Topics

***Sitecore Healthcheck module by Mihály Árvai - Mirum***

***Sitecore DEF: migration Lego for Sitecore developers by Balázs Kerper - ALLWIN***

---

### Agenda

- 18:00 - 18:05: Arriving
- 18:05 - 18:50: Sitecore Healthcheck module
- 18:50 - 19:00: Break
- 19:00 - 19:45: Sitecore DEF: migration Lego for Sitecore developers
- 19:45 - 20:00: Closing

---

The presentations will be held in English. Ask your questions or add your comments to the presentations while it's running. Streaming platform will be chosen soon and you will be informed! RSVP to the event to be up to date!

**When (UTC):** Thursday, July 02, 2020 6:00 PM

**Where:** RSVP to the meetup to join online!

**[RSVP to this Event](https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Budapest/events/270951506/)**